# Some of the completed PayPal transactions are shown pending in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, paypal

WooCommerce Order status showing 'Pending' even when the transaction is complete in PayPal. It's not with all transactions but just some.

Tried reconnecting with new API credentials, checked for any patterns in 'Pending' ones but couldn't find any.

Comment: Is it a WooCommerce plugin that depends on IPN messages? https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/IPNOperations/ --- try using https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-paypal-payments/ if you haven't.